# Liouville's Condition and Rational Numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Liouville’s condition for the Liouville numbers is:

$$0<\left|x-\frac{p_n}{q_n}\right|<\frac{1}{{q^n}_{n\ }}$$

Suppose $x$ is $\frac{c}{d}$

with $c$ and $d$ being members of the positive integers and d being greater than 0 and $p_n$ and $q_n$ being positive integers with $q_n$ being greater than zero. Would Liouville’s condition still hold if $p_n$ and $q_n$ were both positive rational numbers as well? It would seem that this is the case.

For:

$$c=\sum_{k=o}^{\infty}\frac{\left(c-1\right)^k}{c^k}=\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}{(1+\frac{{(c-1)}^{2^k}}{c^{2^k}}})$$

$$d=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{{(d-1)}^k}{d^k}=\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{{{(d}^{2^k}+(d-1)}^{2^k})}{d^{2^k}}}$$

So
$\frac{c}{d}$
Is equivalent to

$$\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{d^{2^k}{{(c}^{2^k}+(c-1)}^{2^k})}{c^{2^k}{{(d}^{2^k}+(d-1)}^{2^k})}$$

So that

$$p_n=q_n\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{{{(c}^{2^k}+(c-1)}^{2^k})}{c^{2^k}}$$

$$q_n=\prod_{k=0}^{n}\frac{{{(d}^{2^k}+(d-1)}^{2^k})}{d^{2^k}}$$

$$\frac{p_n}{q_n}=\prod_{k=0}^{n}\frac{d^{2^n}{{(c}^{2^n}+(c-1)}^{2^n})}{c^{2^n}{{(d}^{2^n}+(d-1)}^{2^n})}$$

Which is equivalent to

$$\frac{p_n}{q_n}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{{{(c}^{2^k}+(c-1)}^{2^k})}{c^{2^k}}\times\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{d^{2^k}}{{{(d}^{2^k}+(d-1)}^{2^k})}$$

Comment: Wasn't this debunked in your last question?

Answer (score 1):

you are misreading the Liouville condition which claims that if something happens with integral $c_n,d_n$ than the number is transcendental which is true; constructing special rationals $p_n,q_n$ out of these $c_n,d_n$ and showing that if Liouville holds for these SPECIAL $ p_n,q_n$'s then the number is transcendental is a tautology so no problem (note that you don't have to go to all the trouble in your post, just replace $q_n, p_n$ with $q_n +\epsilon_n, p_n+\eta_n, \epsilon_n, \eta_n$ small enough rationals and the Liouville condition will still hold for those too)

However from here to the claim that if there are rationals $p_n,q_n$ for which Liouville holds, then the number is transcendental is a vast logical gap

For example,  it is quite trivial that $\frac{n-1}{2n+1}=|1-\frac{1/{2n+1}}{1/{3n}}|< (3n)^n=(1/(1/3n))^n$ and $1$ is quite rational.

Similarly $1/(n+1)=|1-\frac{1}{1+1/n}| < 1/(1+1/n)^n, n>100$ say since $1/(1+1/n)^n \to 1/e$ so one has easy counter-examples with $q_n>1$

Comment: I thought that $p_n$ and $q_n$ had to be related to x in order for Liouville's condition to work. Otherwise, I'm not saying that $p_n$ and $q_n$ can be any number.

Comment: by definition a Liouville number is one for which there is $p_n,q_n$ a sequence of (relatively prime) integers s.t $|x-p_n/q_n| \le 1/q_n^n$; I showed that if you allow $p_n,q_n$ rationals (and even if you require $q_n >1$) then $1$ satisfies the condition; note also that Liouville numbers while uncountable are relatively few as most transcendental numbers are of Mahler type $S$ ($|P(x)|$ cannot be too small relative to the "size" of $P$ for any integer polynomial, while Liouville numbers have $|P(x)|$ very small for the degree one polynomials $q_nz-p_n$ - so they are type U

Comment: @ Conrad, couldn’t you modify Liouville’s condition to allow $p_n$ and  $q_n$ to be rational by taking the inverse of $q_n$?

Comment: For example:
$$Let\ a_n\ =\frac{1}{2n+1}$$
Let $$\ b_n\ =\frac{1}{3n}$$
$$\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{\frac{1}{2n+1}}{\frac{1}{3n}}=\frac{3n}{2n+1}$$

Take the inverse of $b_n$ which is $3n$
$$0<\left|1-\frac{3n}{2n+1}\right|<\frac{1}{{3n}^n}$$

$$0<\left|\frac{-n+1}{2n+1}\right|>\frac{1}{{3n}^n}$$

Comment: Similarly:
 $$\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{1}{\frac{n+1}{n}}=\frac{\frac{1}{n+1}}{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Let $$a_n=\frac{1}{n+1}$$.
Let $$b_n=\frac{1}{n}$$
Take the$$\ inverse\ of \ b_n$$
$$\left|1-\frac{n}{n+1}\right|>\frac{1}{n^n}$$

Comment: I do not understand the point of the above - Liouville numbers have a specific definition to insure their irrationality degree is infinity (or informally they can be approximated extremely well by rationals, or if you want despite that they are transcendent they are the closest irrationals to rationals in a sense) - the definition requires $p_n,q_n$ to be integral - and then obviously one can tinker with them in many ways, but we still need them integrals as a starting point

Comment: I strongly recommend taking  a look at the book by Burger and Tubbs Making Transcendence Transparent, https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387214443, which is fairly elementary at least to start with and presents the reasoning behind all these things quite well - as noted the fundamental fact that allows the theory to be developed is that any non-zero integer is at least $1$ in absolute value and that's why you need integers in an essential way

Answer (score 0):

Liouville’s condition can be generalized to include rational numbers $p_n$ and $q_n$.

For suppose x= 7

So the geometric series for 7 is

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{7^k}{8^k}$
Let $p_n$ equal $$q_n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{7^k}{8^k}$$.
Then let $q_n$ equal $$\frac{8^n}{7^n}$$
$$0<\left|7-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{7^k}{8^k}\right|>(\frac{7^n}{8^n})^n$$